# Why was SF Stateless Web API template removed?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In the picture below we can see in the year 2018 in VS2017 there is no Stateless Web API template in Service Fabric templates in VS. Why was this removed and what are it's replacements?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time you took the first screenshot, probably using *.NET SDK 2.8* or earlier and *SF tools for VS 1.7* and earlier, Service Fabric and the WebApi templates were based on dot net framework only.

The releases that came after Service Fabric .NET SDK 3.0 and SF tools for VS 2.0 , like the one in the screenshot, started a migration to .net standard 2, now you can target dot net framework or dot net core using the same libraries targeting .Net Standard. For A while you had both templates available, now everything is based on core.

The main difference between the old and the new is that the previous templates you used dot net framework 4.6.2 + Owin, now you use AspNet Core with any framework compatible with the .Net Standard 2.

You might get more info from these release notes:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2017/09/25/service-fabric-6-0-release/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/01/26/service-fabric-6-1-release/